# Check Win Form Is closing or not in other event

Tags: c#, events

Suppose I have a `TextBox` with a leave event. When I click on the close button of the ControlBox of the WinForm, first the leave event of the `TextBox` is called and then the `FormClosing` event, but I want the `FormClosing` event directly without the leave event to occure on above scenario.

What do I have to add to my leave event in order to make this work?

Comment: Before asking the question try to search it. Google it.

Comment: Please Read Question Properly.

Comment: I Want To Check Whether form is going to close In All Other Event Of Form and its control. If you have one TextBox on Form with its Leave event you Press Close Button With Executing Of That Leave event than Application execute that Leave event first and than closing From. But I want  to check in that Leave event of TextBox that Form is going to close or not. understood ?

Comment: no one here work for you ...

Comment: @hardik your Leave event will fire **before** your Form Close/Closing events, it has no way of knowing that the form is closing because it **hasn't happened yet**. the only way that I could possible think to do it is to introduce a delay, which as a user I would find extremely annoying.

Comment: @MarkHall Would you please give me example for that ?

Comment: Please show your efforts not your homework!!!

Comment: Is the purpose of this to prevent data from being stored into a database when your form closes ?

Comment: The question is an indication of a badly written OnLeave event. The best solution here is to restructure your logic.

Comment: @MarkHall , It is a **performance** related Issue. see, i put the logic of fetch data from database with the text written in that TextBox and fill grid (Mention There are 1000 of records). though user wants to close that form , The code written in Leave Event will be executed.

Comment: @HenkHolterman , **It is not badly written OnLeave Event But it is a requirement which mention in above comment**.

Comment: @hardik. I see what you are doing. But as I said earlier the form close has not even been initiated  when the leave event is fired.

Comment: @MarkHall , can we get which is the **next event** will going to execute in **currently executing event** ?

Comment: @hardik since windows is message based you possibly could pinvoke looking for certain messages. but **no** there is no way to get the next event during the currently executing event that I know of, hence the answer that I gave. I know I am repeating my self. The sequence of events for what you are asking is MouseLeave, MouseDown, MouseUp then finally FormClose. There is a good chance that your Leave event has finished before your FormClose event is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the logic out of your `LostFocus` event put it into a separate subroutine. Create a timer with a 10 to 100 ms interval. start that in your Leave Event. In the Timers Tick Event Handler check for whether or not the Form is closing if not run your Subroutine.  This is an example of what I am talking about, This can **very** quickly become unmaintainable if you have a lot of control events to intercept, and you will also lose the EventArgs data from your EventHandlers.

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private bool closing;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void textBox1_Leave(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = true;
    }

    private void TextBox1LeaveMethod()
    {
        textBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
    }

    private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        timer1.Enabled = false;
        if (!closing)
            TextBox1LeaveMethod();
    }

    private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
    {
        closing = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: This will work, but seriously OP, your design is bad if this what solves your problem

Comment: @TzahMama I totally agree with your statement, the only reason I can think of needing something like this is if the OP is writing data to a database upon losing focus of his textbox. He really needs to give us more data on what he is trying to do.

Comment: I know, I'm just trying to emphasize what you and Henk Holterman said.